# how to access the property inside a collection inside an array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a collection which has an array in it as item and i want to know how can i access it in my code here is the `dd` of the collection :

```
Collection {#990
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => RoomPricingHistory {#971
      #fillable: array:19 [
        0 => "accommodation_room_id"
        1 => "net_price"
        2 => "sales_price"
        3 => "extra_bed_price"
        4 => "half_charge_price"
        5 => "half_board_price"
        6 => "full_board_price"
        7 => "foreign_net_price"
        8 => "foreign_sales_price"
        9 => "foreign_extra_bed_price"
        10 => "foreign_half_charge_price"
        11 => "foreign_half_board_price"
        12 => "foreign_full_board_price"
        13 => "operator_id"
        14 => "commission_percent"
        15 => "discount_percent"
        16 => "from_date"
        17 => "to_date"
        18 => "is_deleted"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "room_pricing_histories"
      #primaryKey: "id"
```

and here is my try for code :

```
 $sum_price[] = $room_price[$i]->sales_price;
```

its inside a for loop but i get this error :

> Property [sales_price] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: show the code how you are getting this collection. cause on your sample `fillable`, but not an `attributes`

Comment: The $room_price[$i] is of type `RoomPricingHistory` and your RoomPricingHistory is not a class, but it is a collection. So, `$room_price[$i]->sales_price` is wrong

Comment: $data[0]['sales_price'];